# MongoDB C# Get all documents from a list of IDs

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a list of Ids

```
List<string> Ids;
```

and I would like to retrieve all the documents matching these Ids.

There are solutions on the web:

```
var ids = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var query = Query.In("name", BsonArray.Create(ids));
var items = collection.Find(query);
```

but they're all with the old C# driver and with the (not so new anymore) 2.2.4 driver the API has changed and I can't find how to build this query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

please see snippet below (made using LINQPad)

```
void Main()
{
    // To directly connect to a single MongoDB server
    // or use a connection string
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");


var collectionEmpInfo = database.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee");
Employee EmpInfo = new Employee
{

    EmpID = "103",
    EmpName = "John",
    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
    EmpMobile = new List<Mobile>
    {
        new Mobile{ MobNumber = "55566610", IsPreferred = true, MobID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId() },
        new Mobile{ MobNumber = "55566611", IsPreferred = false, MobID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId() },
    }
};
//collectionEmpInfo.InsertOne(EmpInfo);

var filterDef = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Employee>();
var filter = filterDef.In(x=>x.EmpID , new[]{"101","102"});
filter.Dump();
var empList = collectionEmpInfo.Find(filter).ToList();
empList.Dump();
}
public class Employee
{
   public ObjectId Id  { get; set; }
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public List<Mobile> EmpMobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Mobile
{
    public ObjectId MobID { get; set; }
    public string MobNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }
}
```

and results screenshot

[image: linquPaDscreenShot]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! and +1 for making me discover LINQPad :)

Comment: As an addendum, a lot of the examples you see will use the Static Helper class `Builders<TDocument>`.  So in this case you can do:
`var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.In(x => x.EmpID, new[]{"101","102"});`

Comment: Thanks, now I need to find out how to do this without using an explicit DTO class, ie using raw `BsonDocument` instead of `Employee` - maybe we can an addendum to this answer once figured out

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be the current equivalent of what you were attempting:

```
var ids = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("name", ids);
var items = collection.Find(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this recently.

Using the new driver (v2.14.X) this can be achieved with the `$in` operator.  [This Mongo link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver/expressions/#in) describes the `$in` functionality reasonably well.

You can either apply the LINQ format:

```
var ids = new List<string> {"id1", "id2", "etc"};
someMongoCollection.Find(o => o.Any(i => ids.Contains(o.Id));
```

The LINQ format works well except for cases where you're trying to chain queries together (i.e. if you are querying with optional data, so `int[] ages`, `string[] ids`, etc.). In that case you effectively want to build up the query as necessary.

For that application I use the native mongo format (also described in [the Mongo link above](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver/expressions/#in)).

```json
{ Id: { $in: ["id1", "id2", "etc"] } }
```

This is passed as a string to create a BsonDocument which is then used as the filter on the `.Find()` operation. You can add more filters as necessary. More information on passing in data to create `BsonDocument` objects can be found at [this link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/bson/bson_document/).

See example code snip below:

```
// 1 - init base filter (this fetches everything)
var filter = new BsonDocument();  

// 2 - init id data
var ids = new List<string> {"id1", "id2", "etc"};
var idsString = ids.ConvertAll(i => $"\"{i}\"");

// 3 - create the mongo formatted query and generate the BsonDocument
var bsonToParse = $"{{ \"Id\": {{ $in: [{string.Join(",", idsString )}] }} }}";
var idsFilterBson = BsonDocument.Parse(bsonToParse);

// 4 - add the BsonDocument to the already existing filter
filter.Add(idsFilterBson);

// perform steps 2-4 for any other optional query data

// run the final find operation
var dataFromDb = await someMongoCollection.Find(filter).Limit(limit).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

with latest c# mongo driver you also can leverage LINQ support:

```
var results = this.mongoClient.GetCollection<Employee>()
                              .AsQueryable()
                              .Where(x => idList.Contains(x.Id))
                              .ToList();
```